# Clarification on the term

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I came across the following statement when reading Section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9803019.pdf):

> For an oriented 2-plane field $\xi$, let $d(\xi) \in \mathbb{Z}$ denote the divisibility of the Chern class, so that $c_1(\xi)$ equals $d(\xi)$ times a primitive class in $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ modulo torsion, and $d(\xi) = 0$ if $c_1(\xi)$ is of finite order.

The grammar and clarity can be improved as follows:

Here, $M$ is a closed, connected 3-manifold. While viewing $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ as an abelian group, I'm uncertain about the terms "primitive class" and "divisibility mod torsion." Could someone clarify these notions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to improve here.  It is very clear what $d(\xi)$ is.

---

Consider a torsion-free abelian group $G$, and a nonzero element $g\in G$:

- the *divisibility* $d(g)$ is the largest integer $n\geq 1$ such that there exists $h\in G$ with $g=nh$.  (If for every $n$ you can find $h$, we say $g$ is infinitely divisible.)
- $g$ is *primitive* if $d(g)=1$, i.e., it is not divisible by any integer $>1$.

Now you have the (finitely-generated) abelian group $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$, so you can mod out its torsion subgroup to get yourself a torsion-free abelian group and consider the image of $c_1(\xi)$ in $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})/H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})_{\mathrm{tors}}\cong\mathbb{Z}^{b^2(M)}$ and get $d(\xi):=d(c_1(\xi)+H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})_{\mathrm{tors}})$.  Finally we also deal with the case $c_1(\xi)\in H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})_{\mathrm{tors}}$.